# How To Add RecyclerView With Cardview In A TabLayout ViewPager - Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-tablayout

Good day, I just would like to ask if, how do I implement this one - RecyclerView-CardView inside a Fragment layout. I'm new to Android Dev (Doing Self-learning Stuff).

I just include my layout (cardview_org.xml) in the Organization-Tab for sample view on how it looks like. I created 3 cardviews and 3 rows_list.xml (recyclerview) , each tab (different design and data to be shown).

My main question is, how do I make this one possible? And in each every classes of these fragments, do i need to override onCreate() and put those adapters,initialize RecyclerView and etc on it's own classes?- from Android documentation - fragment life cycle.

These are the sites for my reference on making this thing. [Android Warriors](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/11/android-recyclerview-example.html) - [Android ReyclerView with Animations](http://www.raywenderlich.com/103367/material-design)

[image: Tablayout-ViewPager]

Sorry for this tricky questions, but hoping you get what I mean.
If you can provide video links or weblinks, I humbly appreciate it..
Many Thank you in Advance.

Comment: checkout this [material design demo](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)

Comment: I have already checked this cheesesquare stuff time ago :( 
Can I ask you one more thing? What does inflater/layout inflater mean in android? 
"Is it to cause to open"? @gj_

Comment: check [this question about inflation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576330/what-does-it-mean-to-inflate-a-view-from-an-xml-file)

Comment: @gj_ :) Many Thanks for the info. I will do my best to understand these things - cheesesquare. I search for a video tutorial for this one but find none (How to populate tablayout/tabs with recyclerview-cardview). :) hehe..

Comment: @RoCk: check this http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-material-design-3-android.html