# Why should i exactly write that way in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm beginner in Kotlin for Android. I have some stupid questions which i can't find answers.

First question. For Example i have a code like this

```
class myAdapter(context: Context, val list: List<DataSource>)
: ArrayAdapter<DataSource>(context, 0, list){
```

If i write like that (without arguments)

```
class myAdapter(context: Context, val list: List<DataSource>)
: ArrayAdapter<DataSource>(){
```

then intellij give me out this error: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied. Why should i to provide arguments to ArrayAdapter and what are they affected?

Second question. For example, i have a code:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

    val lf: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val row = lf.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view, parent, false)

    val view_icon = row.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.icon)
    val view_title = row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title)
    val view_subtitle = row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.subtitle)

    val ds: DataSource = list[position]
    view_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_folder_black_24dp)
    view_title.text = ds.ds_title
    view_subtitle.text = ds.ds_subtitle

    return row
}
```

What's means the "row" variable and why should i to assign "inflate" to it? How explain it with words? If i don't assign, then inflate will not work.
And what's means this:

```
list[position]
```

Where can i read about it? Kotlin just break down my mind.

Comment: Although you're focused on Android development, understanding the Kotlin language will help you tremendously: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why should i to provide arguments to ArrayAdapter and what are they affected?

Basically when you have a line like `class MyClass(xxx) : SuperClass(yyy)` it means you're creating a new class called `MyClass` with a constructor that takes 1 argument `xxx` and it extends `SuperClass` – of which you're calling the constructor with argument `yyy`.

Now, putting that in the context of your example, you're first trying to call the `ArrayAdapter`'s constructor with 3 arguments – a `Context`, an `int` and a`List` – which exists and can be called. However `ArrayAdapter` doesn't have any constructor with no arguments, hence the compilation error.

As for the second question, you can read more on the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576330/what-does-it-mean-to-inflate-a-view-from-an-xml-file) for example – I think you'll find plenty of material online – but basically "inflate" means "render a UI element", so `row` is the variable that contains a reference to the row you just inflated.