# id names are red in Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I made a very basic dice roll app (in Kotlin) using Android Studio with an imageView and a button. The imageView's id is "imageView" and the button's id is "button". But in the MainActivity.kt file the id names are red in colour and when I hover over them it says "unresolved reference: imageView (or button)"
Why is this happening and how do I solve this?

The id names are same on both the activity_main.xml and MainActivity.kt file:

[image: [Screenshot of code sample][1]*]

Comment: have you imported the layout?

Comment: Can you provide me the import section as well as your build.gradle of app.

Comment: are you using Kotlin android extensions plugin ?

Comment: Which version of kotlin you are using?

Comment: I highly recommed using ViewBind instead of Kotlin extensions. It is deprecated in kotlin version 1.4.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity needs to know what those names refer to, the platform doesn't automatically link views [inflated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576330/what-does-it-mean-to-inflate-a-view-from-an-xml-file) from an XML layout file. Historically this is done in Android by calling the `findViewById()` method like this:

```
lateinit var myTextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceBundle: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceBundle)
    // The layout file is "inflated" automatically here
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_name)

    // Then we can assign a reference to views by ID:
    myTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view_name)
}
```

Since then, shortcuts have come around: [Butterknife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), [Kotlin Synthetics](https://medium.com/coding-blocks/goodbye-findviewbyid-say-hello-to-synthetic-binding-in-kotlin-d3727bd8438e), or the current accepted standard, [Jetpack View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding). if you just need to grab a few views quick call `findViewByid()` but as you work with Android it's worth taking the time to enable View Binding to cut down on this boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

just restart by using invalidate caches/Restart as you seeing this image and after this clean and then rebuild your project

[image: Android Studio Image]

Comment: wrong, this won't fix the problem, this isn't an IDE bug, the views can't be found

Comment: just use viewBinding, it will solve this issue

Answer (score -1):

You have to use kotlin extension.
In your `app gradle.build` add apply plugin: `'kotlin-android-extensions'`
In your class add import for import `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout>.*` where  is the filename of your layout.

Comment: kotlin synthetics are deprecated