# What exact call initiate the drawing of a view on screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

I was trying to understand what's the meaning of inflating a view and found this topic:

[What does it mean to inflate a view from and xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576330/5186781)

But I was not satisfied by the accepted answer, as it mention that inflating a view causes its rendering, while I think it is only responsible of the conversion of the XML layouts into the corresponding code by building the View objects, and I'm wondering if it's the case or not, and if not, what can initiate the  drawing of the view on screen?

Can anyone clarify my questioning by providing trusted or official documentation?

Comment: Why not post it as a comment in the same thread?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community, My question is quite simple, and I formulated it twice, it is pretty understandable for someone who want to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Every subclass of `View` overrides the `onDraw()` method from the `View` class. This is where the `View` actually specifies how it will be drawn on the screen. All drawing takes place on the `View`'s `Canvas`, and the dimensions of the `Canvas` are specified by the width and height attributes you set in your layout file for that `View`.

For instance, here's the `onDraw()` method for `TextView`:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr0-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#4738

Comment: Does the view object automatically draw itself when it's created?

Comment: That's correct, yes. Although it's more likely the framework itself calling this method at this point rather than the object calling it on itself.